# How to run a java script (or some) with ajax from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I have several ajax scripts in the base body django template. I want to run them in a separate js file, but the scripts do not work from a file.

*My script in the body template (this is a working code.):*

```
<!--Add product to the cart after press Add button-->
    <script>
      $(document).on('click', '#add-button', function (e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var prodid = $('#add-button').val();

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '{% url "add_cart" %}',
              data: {
                  product_id: $('#add-button').val(),
                  quantity: $('#qty').val(),
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                  action: 'POST'
              },
              success: function (json) {
                document.getElementById('cart_icon_count').innerHTML = json.qty;
              },
              error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
          });
      })
    </script>
```

Than delete script from body and copy in js file:

*my_js.js*

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-button', function (e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var prodid = $('#add-button').val();

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '{% url "add_cart" %}',
              data: {
                  product_id: $('#add-button').val(),
                  quantity: $('#qty').val(),
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                  action: 'POST'
              },
              success: function (json) {
                document.getElementById('cart_icon_count').innerHTML = json.qty;
              },
              error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
          });
      })
```

and in the body:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/my_js.js' %}"></script>
```

The usual java script function works this way, but for some reason this script does not.
Any ideas for running one or more of these scripts from a separate file?

Comment: The `'{% url "add_cart" %}'` part in a separate JS file will just be an ordinary string, not replaced before sending to the browser

Comment: url="add_cart"? Not working. 'add_cart' - view name

Comment: Put it in the body template, then go to a browser and view source, then you'll know what it was originally replaced with.

Comment: {% url "add_cart" %} replaced with /cart/add_cart/. I copy it in url in js, but it still not working. In consol i see error 403 Forbidden. URL request: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add_cart/ - the same if I use script in html

Answer (score 0):

Thank's **qrsngky** - you helped me figure it out 50% and guided me to the right solution!

{% url "add_cart" %} I replaced with "/cart/add_cart/".

Error 403 Forbidden - the problem was in csrftoken.

I add in my base.html

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}"; </script>
```

and in 'js/my_js.js' add `csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN`

Similar I put {% url "add_cart" %} in variable in the body.html.

And everything worked!